# Condense Y-Ticks to be useful

Tags: python, matplotlib, yticks

Trying to plot a set of points where a couple of the points have extreme Y values.  Is there a way to showcase those values on a graph without losing the value of the other points.  For example:

`[(1, 10), (2, 33), (3, 100000), (4, 17), (5, 45), (6, 8), (7, 950000)]`

I'm picturing a graph with Y ticks 0-50 and then similar sized gap between 50-100000 to showcase the extreme point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether `matplotlib` can do it automatically, but there are several things you try:

- Use a log-scale y-axis, i.e. `ax.set_yscale('log')`. This will to some extent decrease the difference between regular points and outlier points, but you will still see all regular data lying at the bottom of the graph.
- Manually change the y-value of the outliers to some not-that-extreme value. You can later show those points are of some value by manually setting display-content of y-axis using `plt.yticks(actual_data_array, what_to_display_array)`
- Generate a regular (high enough) plot, then do image processing later to cut the middle part of the image. There might be a better way, but one way to do that would be `plt.savefig` to save the plot, `matplotlib.image.imread` to read the plot, and finally process it using `plt.imshow(np.concatenate((image_data[:100], image_data[-100:]), 0))`

Here is an example of the second method I was talking about:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array(((1, 10), (2, 33), (3, 100000), (4, 17), (5, 45), (6, 8), (7, 950000)), 'f')

# scale the array so that matplotlib can plot it "uniformly"
a[a[:,1]>99999,1] = a[a[:,1]>99999,1] / 20000 + 55

plt.plot(*a.T)

# do the displaying trick 
plt.yticks(np.r_[np.linspace(0, 50, 5),
                 np.linspace(100000/20000+55, 950000/20000+55, 5)],
           np.r_[np.linspace(0, 50, 5, dtype='i'),
                 np.linspace(100000, 950000, 5, dtype='i')])

plt.grid()
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is promising, let me give it a shot